# How to apply layouts for different url with same actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have three controllers with three actions:

- List
- View
- Info

The only difference between controllers are selected layout and url.

First i used `RenderPartial` - but it is still a lot of code duplication (mainly in actions).

So i want in some way to avoid this - for example create only one controller and configurate routes, so it choices right layout for different urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how come controller defines your layout? this is a bad practice. remember that in MVC the VIEW layer is for defining the layout.

Each view file can override default shared Layout file with

```
@{
   Layout = "path/to/your/layout.cshtml";  
}
```

and you can provide that value dynamically with ViewBag for example.

Comment: For each controller i have own sets of views (for each controller views are same - now i try to get rid of this) - so overall i have 3x3 views. In view i define layout, as you described.

So as i understand - best approach would be in controller find out  required layout (from url) and pass it to the view.

Comment: I wouldn't put that into url, I'd rather save the chosen layout in Profile or Cookie. Why do you want to store it in URL ?

Comment: Because i'm using these urls "site.net/en/Controller1/List/", "site.net/en/Controller2/List/" - result should be same content, but different layout. Now i want that these requests routed to one controller, where i could set layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the View File, that should be used by a Controller.

```
return View("~/Views/Posts/Index.cshtml", db.Posts.ToList())
```

This way you can use the same template for different Controller methods.